# Airbags set off while car being serviced

Tags: dtc, supplemental-restraint-system

Took a 2015 Mitsubishi RVR (Outlander) AWD into a mechanic to have the Airbag Service warning looked at- car had been jump started from a dead battery and the Service warning was flashing.

Somehow they got the airbags to deploy during examining it (BANG), and they're claiming a faulty module was to blame.

Is it at all possible that a fault in the vehicle would cause this, while it was being serviced, as opposed to an error on the part of the mechanic?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a legal question, not related to repair.

Comment: @GdD Rephrased. I'm not interested in the legal implications, only technically how this could happen.

Comment: That makes much sense now, close vote retracted.

Comment: Was it a "real" mechanic, ideally from the dealership, or some "mr-fix-it"?
Depending on your jurisdiction, an mechanic might need an license to work on airbags. Perhaps that is some way you can proceed.

Comment: @Martin It was a chain of repair shops. Pretty legit. I would expect them to tell me if they couldn't service it.

Comment: Sounds more likely to be error from the tech. Something like having switch on while plugging/unplugging module but there is no way to prove either way.

Comment: Given there were faults already evident as well as a flat battery, then the mechanic may not be the cause - depends on what faults are/were present.

Comment: Airbags are tripped by sensors, I suppose a sensor malfunction could cause that, but following the right procedure would have prevented deployment. The first rule is disconnect the battery when working on airbags!

Comment: @GdD - No, the first step is to read the codes. You unplug the battery and the codes are gone. Reading the codes first should give you a clue as to what's going on in the system.  Second step is to disconnect the battery before ever touching a connector. Third step is to discharge residual energy in the system.

Comment: Agreed @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, my comment was saying that you always disconnect the power before you work on the mechanical or electrical elements. Reading the codes would definitely be the first step, and wouldn't cause them to deploy.

Comment: The vehicle had a brand new battery in it, and had been driven at least 50 miles/100km since.